# Freeing and Reusing GPU in Tensorflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cuda, tensorflow2.0, numba

I would like to free and Reuse the GPU while using Tensorflow in a jupyter notebook.

I imagine a workflow like this:

1. Make a TF calculation.
2. Free the GPU
3. Wait a while
4. Step 1. again.

This is the code i use right no. Steps 1 to 3 are working step 4 is not:

```py
import time

import tensorflow as tf
from numba import cuda 


def free_gpu():
    device = cuda.get_current_device()
    cuda.close()

def test_calc():
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])   
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

    # Run on the GPU
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

test_calc()
free_gpu()
time.sleep(10)
test_calc()
```

If i run this code in Jupyter Notebooks my kernel just dies.
Is there a alternetiv to `cuda.close()` and `cuda.close()` that frees the GPU while not breaking TF?

Comment: The really short answer is don't call `numba.cuda.close()`. That kills the context that tensorflow is bound to and then nothing will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, building somewhat of what @talonmies said, do not bring `numba` into this whatsoever. It's basically incompatible with the TensorFlow API.

Here is a solution where you completely free the GPU. Basically, you can launch the TF computations in a separate process, return any result that you care about, and then close the process. TensorFlow notably has issues regarding freeing GPU memory.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import tensorflow as tf

def test_calc(q):
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

    # Run on the GPU
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
    q.put(c.numpy())

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=test_calc, args=(q,))
p.start()
p.join()
result = q.get()
```

Comment: That is a pretty invasive approach. You could probably achieve the same thing using `with tf.device('/GPU:0'): ...` to trigger resource cleanup without resorting to process separation or repeated device context creation and destruction, but thanks for adding an answer

Comment: @talonmies, I tried the `with tf.device`, but that did not help with the OOM. In my case it appears the 2nd time, after I successfully call predict the 1st time. Will try the invasive approach next.